# Tomcat - Redirect to Error Page when ServletContextListener fails

Tags: java, tomcat

When Tomcat starts it calls my ServletContextListener to obtain a database connection, which I will later use in other servlets with getServletContext(). It is called in my web.xml as:
    `listener
 
     listener-class org.ppdc.database.DBCPoolingListener /listener-class
 
     /listener>` 

(I removed the < > because they wouldn't display properly in this message.>
If I cannot connect to the database when Tomcat starts up I get a 404 error, because Tomcat cannot start the application.

How can I redirect the user to a custom error page at this point? I tried the following in my web.xml (I have the < > brackets in the original):
    (error-page)
        (error-code404/error-code)
        (location/file_not_found.html/location)
    (/error-page)

Any ideas on how to redirect a user to one of my error pages when Tomcat tries to start the application?

Thanks
Vic

Comment: You don't have to type HTML ( though you can ), and code can be escaped with a button that has 0's and 1's in it.

Comment: Hi Alexander. I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you post an example in a comment of what it would like?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read this first -> http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.  When you ask or edit a question, on top of the editing area, there are few icons.  All of them automate typing that is described in the editing help.  Also it is customary on SO to accept or upvote the answers if they were helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the editing page. I had looked in the faq's but didn't come across that page, and I obviously missed the icons too. I am new to SO and can't upvote answers yet, but I just set your answer as my accepted answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem, happy coding. One more thing, if you start your comment with `@UserName`( like `@Vic` at the start of this comment ) then it would be brought to the attention of said user, and you may receive reply to your question much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application fails to load, then that's it.  Tomcat is not running it and does not serve your error-pages.

So, if you want to handle a half-dead state, you need to start in a half-dead state.  Fortunately, the code in your servlets can be spared checks whether the app is half-dead if you install a Filter, that does it before control is transfered to any servlet.

Declare a filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>IsHalfDeadFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>my.package.IsHalfDeadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>IsHalfDeadFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then implement `doFilter` method to redirect to your error page.

```
@Override
public void doFilter (
        final ServletRequest request,
        final ServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain chain
    ) throws
        IOException,
        ServletException
{
    if ( isHalfDead )
    {
        // redirect to error page
        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter( request, response );
}
```

Read more about Filters [here](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html)

Comment: Thanks again Alexander. This looks like it will work for me. I'll investigate it further, starting with the link you provided.